# Json import into pandas DataFrame

Tags: json, pandas

I have next JSON file:

```
{
    "_id": "2105291180380642",
    "firstKey": "1651560",
    "secondKey": "2108270",
    "thirdKey": "4725",
    "fourthKy": "5",
    "userId": "fjbcjsda",
    "subscription": "null",
    "deviceId": "android_ST25i_1264-3545",
    "appId": "1.4",
    "sample": "false",
    "auth": "null",
    "usageType": "s",
    "type": "l",
    "occurredAt": "1374781560092"
}
```

I can prove it on the [JSONlit.com](http://jsonlint.com/) and get `valid JSON` back. 
After I import this file (the file contents only from one line) in Pandas Python and try to create some DataFrame with the command:

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.read_json('test.json')
```

or

```
df = pd.read_json('test.json',orient='columns')
```

I always get a errore message:

```
If using all scalar values, you must must pass an index
```

How I can import JSON file into DataFrame by the using of `read_json`? At the moment this command doesn't know the valid JSON file. My pandas version is `0.13.1`

Comment: This is a tricky one, although it's a valid json file, the format is not one that is supported by any of the recognised [orient](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#orient-options) types. You would have to either add an index to the json file or modify the format so that it can be imported correctly

Comment: What are you expecting the result to look like? I 1 row dataframe where the JSON keys are the columns? In this case a Series is probably what you want: There is the `typ` argument, which parses the file: `s = pd.read_json('tst.json', typ='series')`

Comment: This is a toy example, I have much more lines